# How important is to have the employment certificate stamped?

Tags: germany, certification

I received my employment certificate from my former employer (an IT company in Germany). The letter is printed on a paper with the company's header and is signed by my supervisor (head of the team) and by the head of HR.

However, the letter does not have the usual company stamp on it. I can ask them to print me another version and collect the signatures and the stamp and mail it to me, but I was wondering how necessary or important is this?

**P.S.**: The company told me a stamp for such a letter is not common in Germany. So, they refused to put it there!

Comment: The norm for employment in Germany doesn't sound "company specific" to me

Comment: Every company handles it differently. Mine does Stamp employment cert letters, and a neighbouring firm does not. Both in germany.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In some countries, stamps are no longer necessary. So in these countries, you will have no problem using that certificate.

However, there are other countries in which the stamp rules. If you will need to use that certificate in such country, you may run into problems.

It is difficult to give a definitive answer about what you should do, because it depends on many factors.

You may try to get a stamp on that certificate from the said company, but they might literally not have such stamp to be used.